# node Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I get this error and i cant find the solution my code is proper i think it s video lesson where i can show popular photos from instaram via instagra api but i get this when i try to execute the node is running properly i can t understand my mistake

```
TypeError:\Desktop\instagramApp\views\pages\index.ejs:13
   11| <main>
   12| <div class="row">
>> 13| <% grams.forEach(function(gram)  { %>
   14| <div class="instagram-pic col-sm-3">
   15| <a href="<%= gram.link %>"target="_blank">
   16|  <img src="<%= gram.images.standard_resolution.url %>" class="img-responsive">

Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\Kel3vra\Desktop\instagramApp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:464:12), <anonymous>:23:13)
   at returnedFn (C:\Users\Kel3vra\Desktop\instagramApp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:493:17)
   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Kel3vra\Desktop\instagramApp\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:350:31)
   at View.render (C:\Users\Kel3vra\Desktop\instagramApp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:126:8)
   at tryRender (C:\Users\Kel3vra\Desktop\instagramApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:639:10)
   at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\Kel3vra\Desktop\instagramApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:591:3)
   at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Kel3vra\Desktop\instagramApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:961:7)
   at C:\Users\Kel3vra\Desktop\instagramApp\server.js:24:7
   at handle_error (C:\Users\Kel3vra\Desktop\instagramApp\node_modules\instagram-node\lib\instagram.js:255:14)
   at C:\Users\Kel3vra\Desktop\instagramApp\node_modules\instagram-node\lib\instagram.js:904:16
```

this the code of index.ejs

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <% include ../partials/head %>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body class="container">
        <header>
        <% include ../partials/header %>
        </header>
        <main>
        <div class="row">
        <% grams.forEach(function(gram)  { %>
            <div class="instagram-pic col-sm-3">
            <a href="<%= gram.link %>"target="_blank">
              <img src="<%= gram.images.standard_resolution.url %>" class="img-responsive">
            </a>
            </div>

            <div class="instagram-bar">
                <div class="likes">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
                <%= gram.likes.count %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="comments">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
                <%= gram.comments.count %>
            </div>
          <%  }); %>


         </div>
        </main>

        <footer>
        <% include ../partials/footer %>
        </footer>
    </body>

    </html>
```

and to my server.js

```
var express = require('express');    
var app = express();
var instagram = require('instagram-node').instagram();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));    
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

instagram.use({
  client_id: /************/,
  client_secret: /*************/
});

app.get('/',function (req, res) {
  instagram.media_popular(function (err, medias, remaining, limit) {
    res.render('pages/index',{ grams: medias });
  });
});

app.listen(8080, function (err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("error");
  } else {
    console.log("Listening on port 8080")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable `medias` in this line:

```
res.render('pages/index',{ grams: medias });
```

…is undefined - it is throwing the error when this is first accessed (in the template).

It's possible that the `instagram.media_popular` function is returning an error, which you can check by updating your route to:

```
app.get('/',function (req, res, next) {
  instagram.media_popular(function (err, medias, remaining, limit) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.render('pages/index', { grams: medias });
  });
});
```

(notice the extra `next` at the top, this allows you to pass the error down to the express error handling code)

Comment: after i paste your share  it gives me that:                                                SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
   at Object.parse (native)
   at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kel3vra\Desktop\instagramApp\node_modules\instagram-node\lib\instagram.js:192:27)
   at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:166:7)
   at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:903:12)
   at doNTCallback2 (node.js:439:9)
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)

Comment: I'm facing the same error I did the same as you suggested to throw an error. The error is: Error: APINotFoundError: invalid media id

What media ID? Because I think the media ID is alright according to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...

And the issue was the use of the wrong `client_id` from instagram api...

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and instead of client ID and client Secret I used the Access token and the error was gone.

```
ig.use({
   access_token: 'Enter your access token here'
});
```